# SFSpeechRecognizer init not accepting Locale

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I'm trying to initialise an instance of `SFSpeechRecognizer` but I get the following error `Cannot convert value of type 'Locale' to expected argument type 'Locale'` which doesn't make any sense to me. Bellow is my initialisation code.

```
let speech = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale().initWithLanguageCode(languageCode: "en-US") as! Locale)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
if let speech = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US")) {
     // ...
}
```

Use [init(localeIdentifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nslocale/1414217-init) for initialization.

```
let locale = Locale()
```

This causes:

[image]

Note that `speech` is an optional.

**ALSO:** [here](https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273) you can check iOS Locale Identifiers.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I get this error with your code "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Comment: When you got it? `SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))` should not be the reason.

Comment: That's exactly on this line, I just copied the code and pasted on an empty viewDidLoad to see if it could compile or not.

Comment: [This](https://s21.postimg.org/kstrg0td3/Screen_Shot_2016_10_26_at_1_04_53_PM.png) is what I got :) it works fine for me -as it should-, clean and build...

Comment: I found the problem I had a custom Locale class that I didn't remember about that was causing this issue.